# What's wrong with the User Profile Page alignment?

Tags: bug, status-completed

Sometime earlier today, I started getting this alignment problem on all User Profile pages on EE.SE (both main and meta sites). See an example below:

[image: User Profile glitch]

I added the red rectangles to show the empty spaces that appeared in place of the usual content.

Is it just me? I tried it on Chrome and IE and both showed the same problem.

Here's another screenshot showing more page contents. It looks like the rest of the page is shown on the left column. Before the glitch, the content used to be distributed among two columns.

[image: User Profile glitch 2]

Comment: Same issue, assumed it was related to the design update.

Comment: I noticed it too, figured it had something to do with things being changed to the new format, and that it will settle out soon enough.  Unless this persists until after the design update, it doesn't seem like anything worth bothering SE about.  They probably already that this happened anyway.

Comment: @Olin - I also assumed that it had something to do with deployment of the new design. But since it's going on for a few hours now, I thought someone should report the issue, just in case. I also wanted to check if it was something others were experiencing as well.

Comment: Related on Meta.SE: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267265/sff-and-mi-yodeya-and-other-sites-without-css-update-are-experiencing-odd-link

Comment: @Catija - so there you have it, these sites also have the old User Profile. So it's upon us. Change is coming!

Comment: @Ricardo Unfortunately, while the change is certainly coming eventually, I don't think this is related other than that this is part of why they're making the CSS change in the first place. This is actually the third time this has happened. Not sure what your normal link colors are but sites where the normal link color is not blue have seen this more than once.

Comment: Rats! (thanks for the info, though, @Catija)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry about that. We accidentally [included a wrong file in another file](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/267281/155160).